# Strange domain name appears in Sharing Preferences, source unknown

Tags: macos, network, dns, domain

First of all before anyone asks, I have already set my DNS name in the Terminal with `scutil`, which is reflected on the Terminal prompt and returned by the `hostname` command. I also understand that this is separate from my computer name, which is also set correctly at the top of the Sharing preference pane.

However, there appears to be a *third* name specified somewhere, and it shows up under the File Sharing and Remote Management sections. This is my work machine (A mac mini) and I inherited it from a previous employee so I don't know it's history, but I'm a Mac technician at an IT consultancy and we have seen this problem elsewhere, and it has us stumped. This rogue DNS name that hides somewhere on the system is also what our remote management software grabs to name our client's machines in our system, and since we have no known way to change it it's made reassigning machines to new users a confusing proposition on our end.

Does anybody know what sets the domain names used by the remote management and file sharing services, and where it might get this value from? I have searched through so many configuration files and have come up empty handed. I assume that configd handles this assignment but I don't know how to configure or troubleshoot configd.